# Getting an element as jQuery object from a set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get an element from a jQuery object, but *as* jQuery object?

If I wanted to get the text of elements, presently I'd write it like this:

```
var elements = $(".set");
for (var idx=0; idx<elements.size(); idx++) {
    var text = $(elements.get(idx)).text();
    // do something with text
}
```

Note that I have to wrap `elements.get(idx)` in another jQuery call `$()`.

I realize this isn't that big a deal, I just want to make sure I'm not doing extra work if there is an easier way.

Comment: `.size()` is deprecated, use `.length` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`.eq()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
// returns the third div (zero-indexed) in a jQuery wrapper
var $mydiv = $('div').eq(2);
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I knew they'd have something like that! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Why not go with:

```
$(".set").each(function (idx) {
   var text = $(this).text();
    // do something with text
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$(".set").each( function () {
   var text = $(this).text();
   // do stuff
});
```